# Best Programming Language For An Application Installer

Tags: windows-installer

Alright I am new to programming and I want to make a game installer. Do any of you know what the best programming language for an .EXE application installer? Something like C#, C++, Or C. IDK. Please don't give me hate I'm trying to learn.
Thank You for dealing with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it's going to depend on what you use to make it. For example, if you make it in c# and Visual Studio you can deploy it using the .NET framework. This will give you an installer for your code